# how to validate datefield before select in extjs 3.4

Tags: date, extjs

i am using extjs 3.4 add add datefield in portal for selection of date range.Start date and end date means if i select 28 jan 2014 in start date then i want to validate end date after 28  jan 2014 is display with in 30 days interval only .

and i also want to validate difference between start date and end in only 30 days

```
 {
id:'funnelStartId',
xtype: 'datefield',
format : 'd-M-Y',
editable:false,
emptyText:'Start date',
listeners:{
select: function (value,date){
getFunnelDateRange()    
}
}
},{
id:'funnelEndId',
`enter code here`  xtype: 'datefield',
format : 'd-M-Y',
editable:false,
emptyText:'End date',
listeners:{
select: function (value,date){
getFunnelDateRange()    
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to get a similar behavior to the one you describe by setting the min and max values of the `datefield` on `select`:

```
var dateValidate = function() {
        var dateFld1 = Ext.getCmp('funnelStartId');
        var dateFld2 = Ext.getCmp('funnelEndId');
        startValue = dateFld1.getValue();
        endValue = dateFld2.getValue();
        maxEndValue = startValue.add(Date.DAY, 30);
        if (endValue < startValue || endValue > maxEndValue) {
            dateFld2.setValue(null);
        }
        dateFld2.setMinValue(startValue);
        dateFld2.setMaxValue(maxEndValue);
    }
```

I have a created [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/40i) demonstrating.